# Change Graph in the div using Drop Down List.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, highcharts

**Here is the html code to generate drop-down list -**

```
<form method="post" action="abc.php">
 <select name="dateRange" id="mySelect" size="1" onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
       <option value > Select Duration </option>
       <option value="/abc.php/?dateRange=1d">Last 24 Hours</option>
       <option value="/abc.php/?dateRange=2d">Last 2 Days</option>
       <option value="/abc.php/?dateRange=1w">Last Week</option>
       <option value="/abc.php/?dateRange=2w">Last 2 Weeks</option>
       <option value="/abc.php/?dateRange=1m">Last Month</option>
       <option value="/abc.php/?dateRange=3m">Last 3 Months</option>
       <option value="/abc.php/?dateRange=6m">Last 6 Months</option>
       <option value="/abc.php/?dateRange=1y">Last Year</option>
</select>
```

**Here is js to do something based on the selected value  -**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mySelect').on('change', function () {
  var d = $('#mySelect').val();
  switch (d)
  {
  case "/abc.php/?dateRange=1d":
document.write("<?php echo 'hello!'; ?>");
    break;
  case "/abc.php/?dateRange=2d":
    alert("a");
    break;
  case "/abc.php/?dateRange=1w":
   alert("b");
    break;
  case "/abc.php/?dateRange=2w":
    alert("c");
    break;
  case "/abc.php/?dateRange=1m":
    alert("d");
    break;
  case "/abc.php/?dateRange=3m":
    alert("d");
    break;
  case "/abc.php/?dateRange=6m":
    x="Today is Saturday";
    break;
  case "/abc.php/?dateRange=1y":
   alert("f");
    break;
  }
});
</script>
```

**then i have some high chart graph code which render my graph for the given inputs in the div -**

```
   <div id="container" style="min-width: 4000px; height: 2000px; margin:0px  "> </div>
   <button id="zoom">Zoom </button>
```

here what I want to achieve is that when the value in the drop down list is selected/changed it should display the concerned graph in the same div.
For example, here for the case where `d = "/abc.php/?dateRange=1d"` it should show **hello** in the same div that I am using to render graph.

how i can achieve this ?
please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use an iframe to achieve this?

In your HTML:

```
<div><iframe style="min-width: 4000px; height: 2000px; margin:0px" id="graph" src="about:blank" /></div>
<form method="post" action="abc.php">
<!-- snip -->
```

And then your JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var graphContainer = document.getElementById("graph");
    $('#mySelect').on('change', function () {
        var d = $('#mySelect').val();
        graphContainer.src = d;
    });
</script>
```

I've assumed that the option values you have are relative URLs, which would contain the graph output you're looking for. Based on this assumption, I thought it best to have an iframe render this output, and simply change the source when updating the graph.

Because the change of the drop-down means a different URL, I simply change the source attribute (src) of the iframe each time the dropdown is changed. Because of this, you'll notice the lack of "hello" in my example, as it should be apparent that the iframe's source changes when you change the drop-down value.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap highcharts div inside parent like:

```
<div id="test">
   <span id="tit"></span>
   <div id="container" style="min-width: 4000px; height: 2000px; margin:0px  "> </div>
   <button id="zoom">Zoom </button>
</div>
```

Then load text to span, but chart to container.